# Django razorpay: How to get the order id after payment is complete

Tags: django, razorpay

As per my understanding.

Step1) create Order_id

```
order_amount = 50000
order_currency = 'INR'
order_receipt = 'order_rcptid_11'
notes = {'Shipping address': 'Bommanahalli, Bangalore'}   # OPTIONAL

obj = client.order.create(amount=order_amount, currency=order_currency, receipt=order_receipt, notes=notes)
```

then save order in databas

```
order_id = obj['id']
Orders(
  id=order_id,
  status="pending",
  user=user, 
  razorpay_payment_id="",
  razorpay_order_id="",
  razorpay_signature="").save()
```

Step2 - Pass the order_id to the checkout page

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/payment/success/" method="POST">
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="YOUR_KEY_ID" // Enter the Test API Key ID generated from Dashboard → Settings → API Keys
    data-amount="29935" // Amount is in currency subunits. Hence, 29935 refers to 29935 paise or ₹299.35.
    data-currency="INR"//You can accept international payments by changing the currency code. Contact our Support Team to enable International for your account
    data-order_id="order_CgmcjRh9ti2lP7"//Replace with the order_id generated by you in the backend.
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Acme Corp"
    data-description="A Wild Sheep Chase is the third novel by Japanese author Haruki Murakami"
    data-image="https://example.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
    data-prefill.email="gaurav.kumar@example.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

Step3: Get the reponse on payment completed

```
{
  "razorpay_payment_id": "pay_29QQoUBi66xm2f",
  "razorpay_order_id": "order_9A33XWu170gUtm",
  "razorpay_signature": "9ef4dffbfd84f1318f6739a3ce19f9d85851857ae648f114332d8401e0949a3d"
}
```

Now We have to verify this.

But here we dont know this response is for which order_id as per this image.

[image]

Because i have seen someone using the below to retrieve the order

```
Orders.objects.get(order_id = razorpay_order_id)
```

but this contradicts with the notes in the above image.

If `order_id is not same razorpay_order_id` then the only way to retrieve the order is it to include it in the `callback url` like `/successs/order_id`

So how to do this the right way

Also one more confusing thing i found is that the python library `razorpay` is different from the docs

[image]

And what the docs say:

[image]

and again another confusion is the docs says we can use the python module

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In step 1, with `obj = client.order.create()` and `obj['id']` what you are getting is the `order_id`, and you have to **save** it in the DB corresponding to the Order.

We can blindly trust this created `order_id` since this is created in our server.

And on completing the checkout process of the order, the Razorpay returns      `razorpay_order_id`, this will be the same as our `order_id` unless someone ***manipulated*** it. That's why the documentation says:

> Do not use the `razorpay_order_id` **"returned by the Checkout"**

What does it actually mean is Do not use the `razorpay_order_id` "returned by the Checkout" directly in the

```
client.payment.capture(response['razorpay_payment_id'], ... )
```

without any validations or cross-checking with our previously created `order_id`

#### How to return the order?

Since we have already saved our Order with the order_id,

we can cross-check the `razorpay_order_id` with our `order_id` like in the example you mentioned.

```
trusted_order = Orders.objects.filter(order_id=razorpay_order_id)
```

if there exists a `trusted_order` that is not previously paid then we are safe to use `razorpay_payment_id`.

Comment: `without any validations or cross-checking with our previously created order_id` :: So how do you validate it

Comment: ```trusted_order = Orders.objects.filter(order_id=razorpay_order_id)``` this is oru cross check, if there exist a ```trused_order``` then trusted_order['order_id'] will be same as razorpay_order_id. and you are safe to use the ```trusted_order['order_id']``` in the further process..

Comment: I think this clarifies more clearly. Thank you.

Comment: how refund can be performed ? can u explain?

Comment: @SuryaR AFAIK if the transaction failed, Razorpay automatically refunds the amount within a week from the transaction date, so you don't have to worry about it.